# Panel containing RadioButtonList does not recognize default button

Tags: .net, devexpress, panel, radiobuttonlist, defaultbutton

I have multiple controls within a panel.  The last control within the panel is a radio button list.  The panel has a default button of "Submit", located outside of the panel on tha page.  The page with which the panel is embedded has a couple additional buttons.  When I make the radio button selection and press my Enter key, the "Submit" button is not fired, but the first button on the page.  So what is it about a RB that makes it different enough from a text box or DDL that it won't recognize a panel's default button?  Is there a way to force the RB to use the default?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this button set as the default button <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="yourButton" > ? I think it is from your post but just checking. Just for kicks have you tried setting Page.Form.DefaultButton just to see if the behavior persists?

Comment: @kd7, thanks.  Originally the default button was a part of the form but yes I did move it to the panel, just like in your example. I moved it because there are multiple buttons and links on the page. With a default at page level, I cannot access any links when tabbing to them and using the Enter key, and the other buttons can only be used via the Space Bar.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround, as I **still** do not understand why the radio button works this way.  (I even created a test project with similar controls and didn't have this problem.)  First, I set this property on all of my buttons preceding Submit:`UseSubmitBehavior="false"`.  This will then essentially make my Submit button the go-to, as far as the browser is concerned.

Of course with the defaultButton removed completely, this caused other problems with a drop down list I also had in the panel.  When I took away the defaultButton, I could not longer hit  and still have the Submit function work.  So I needed to keep the defaultButton for the panel.  There are other posts regarding `UseSubmitBehavior`, but I never made this connection.